# access database table row by row sequentially by click on button

Tags: java, mysql

How can I get row by row data sequentially on "label" by clicking button again and again until all row's data access? This problem is come when I want access row from a database table by click on next button to see first row and again click to see second row and so on.

Comment: You could read all rows from database and keep in a list from where you can read it one by one on each click.  That would be much better than keeping a db connection open while waiting for clicks.

Comment: perhaps [JQgrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) can help you on this.

Comment: Retrieve all the records and keep it up in the dataset and when you click the button get it from the dataset based on the prev access.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).